# visual studio c++ problem with two independent projects in a solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I created two projects in a solution in Visual Studio C++.Both of them have the same files including the file containing the main function. But I am unable to execute the projects independently. One of them throws an error. Do all the projects in a solution link to one 
exe/assembly ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the specific error you get? That would help us figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do all the projects in a solution link to one exe/assembly ?

No. However if you want to run several debugging sessions using debuggers integrated into Visual Studio at same time then you have to run several Visual Studios at same time.

It is debugging  only single process per time.

Comment: actually I am trying to debug only one at time.